# Possible to pull github repo in AWS Codepipeline IAC STAGE flow (not source)?

Tags: typescript, github, devops, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have a codepipeline set up using the cdk with typescript. The pipeline successfully sources the github pipeline repo for the code to source, build and deploy. Now i'm wondering about how to integrate the actual infrastructure deployments with the codepipeline- and particularly I would like to *avoid* creating a monorepo for multiple backend lambdas that currently belong to different github repositories.

Is it possible to add a stage/wave that sources from multiple github repos, with each repo containing lambda code with corresponding cdk infrastructure code brought along for that lambda as well?

It seems like searching for this I get mostly answers about the github *source* action, like how to setup the pipeline. But i'd like a similar behavior to happen for the following stages as well, if possible.

I'm also open to feedback about the overall approach here too. I'm newer to devops. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

One way you can approach this is to use git submodules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).